# Error updating softwares

Tags: updates, repository, error-handling

I recently removed some repository by mistake and now i cannot update the softwares using the "software updater". Additionally, when i do a  `sudo apt-get update`  command in the terminal, I get the following message:-

`GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 82EB5823F4FE239D`

How can i correct this and is there any way i can "re-install" all the original Repositories.

P.S : I am a relative noob when it comes to ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution from a blog post to [fix the key error](http://naveenubuntu.blogspot.com/2011/08/fixing-gpg-keys-in-ubuntu.html):

Open the terminal and execute these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 82EB5823F4FE239D
```

These commands are requesting the missing GPG key from the ubuntu keyserver, which I believe should be sufficient to resolve your problem, so now you can:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```